# XAMPP Cannot start mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp

I dont know what happened in my xampp. Yesterday it was okay and now when I open it it gives me this error

```
10:05:28 am  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
10:05:28 am  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:05:28 am  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:05:28 am  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:05:28 am  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:05:28 am  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:05:28 am  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:05:28 am  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I tried several solutions like changing the ports but it doesnt work. Here are my logs from mySQL

```
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-02-03 10:05:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-02-03 10:05:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 5095927588; transaction id 88724
2021-02-03 10:05:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-02-03 10:05:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-02-03 10:05:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

[image]

Comment: Close Skype if its open and restart again

Comment: skype is closed sir @KarthikSekar

Comment: MySQL appears to have started correctly. What are you phpMyAdmin settings?

Comment: Use Windows Task Manager to see if you have Service running with Name of mysql Running.